# Display NSString in table

Tags: xcode, nsstring, uilabel

I have some NSString objects to display in a label, you can think of it as rows of records as in database table. I am wondering if there is a way to display this data in such a table format using Xcode? (Imagine you are doing so in html and it will be straight forward. Is there a similar functionality in Xcode or there is a trick of doing so?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at [UITableView](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEsQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=s5nxT6uCF8Od-wbzraWvAw&usg=AFQjCNFHOOV6Ye5njrJI49tNeR80jfSTzQ&sig2=VlMeRE7sDGhC6vYAmJ73uQ) yet? It sounds like it's pretty much what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think I want a UITableView. Can it actually display the text in a table with several columns and rows as a normal table we see in a database?

Comment: It can, but you have to do some work yourself. Add a couple of UILabels and use a clever layout. Or maybe UICollectionView is better in your case? It's been added recently in iOS 6.0, so only use this if you plan to release the app for iOS 6.0 only. Otherwise, maybe you find something useful here: [CocoaObjects](http://cocoaobjects.com/?s=grid).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction! I am now looking at something called gridview table. And actually I am thinking that I may be able to solve this by making a UIImage of the table plus several labels on it to create the illusion of a real table.

Comment: What do you mean by "making a UIImage of the table"?

Comment: Use photoshop to make an image of a table

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea for several reasons, performance being one of them. What's the problem with subclassing UITableViewCell and using UITableView?